# How can I run a hook before specific task in leiningen?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I set up sassc compiler in my `project.clj` using hooks like this:

`:hooks [leiningen.sassc]`

This way sassc is recompiled every time when I run any task e.g. `lein migratus migrate`

How can I avoid sassc compilation on `migrate` and `test` tasks and do it only on `run`?